# Simple Captcha Solver with Python

Tags: python, captcha, python-tesseract

I'm reaching to you to get some help and advices on creating a "Captcha Solver" using python and any image detection to text package

This is an example of the captcha (it contains only 4 character and its always numbers):
[image][image][image]

I am not sure if I should use a complex solver with AI and CNN and Machine Learning or just something more simple but I feel like I can't find a good tutorial... Instread I just find compagnies selling a package of multiple captcha solving...

Thanks in any case for the time and advice,

Daniel

I have tried to use these :

https://github.com/ptigas/simple-captcha-solver

https://gist.github.com/lobstrio/8010d0a21c48b8c807f0c3820467ee0c

https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) or [Tesseract.JS](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs). You will find plenty of useful tutorials and articles on how to use Tesseract. you might wanna explore some additional Algorithms to reduce the noise in the image.

Comment: SOLVED! 
https://gist.github.com/MrAch26/5e2aa7e73b508f8ba9133d468efa4348